# Using Sockets along with RMI

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I have implemented a RMI solution, where my client program can get a datasource object from a DB pool in a Server program . Both run on local host (I am still a newbiew ;) )

But then I was looking at one of the posts in SO and it mentioned about wrapping a socket first and then use the RMI to access the remote access object.

[Java RMI not closing socket after lease expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227276/547453)

I also read that RMI also uses Sockets internally.

My question is if I have to create a wrapper on the Socket instance and then use RMI, should I create Sockets (server and client sockets) by myself and then use RMI....if yes...then how to do it? I have learnt to create sockets and RMI but not use them together.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. There's no point in transporting DataSources via RMI. If you have RMI you don't need sockets too. You seem to be using technologies just because they're there, rather than satisfying actual design requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan to write and control the protocol for communication between client and server, stick to using an RMI client to interrogate a server and use the RMI server to respond.

Also, a `DataSource` instance is not something you should serialise and distribute to clients.  Typically I would expect that when the client makes requests for data, that the server would use the data source to access data on behalf of the client, then marshall the results and send them back to the client.